# Independent sets in subfield

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ a probability measure on $\mathcal F$. Suppose that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are independent sets belonging to $\mathcal F$. Let $\mathcal F_k$ be the smallest subfield of $\mathcal F$ containing $A_1,\ldots,A_k$. Show that if $A\in \mathcal F_k$, then $A,A_{k+1},\ldots,A_n$ are independent.

I  let $\mathcal X=\{Y\in \mathcal F\mid Y,A_{k+1},\ldots,A_n\}$ are independent. Clearly $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ belong to $\mathcal X$, and we want to show that $\mathcal X$ is a subfield. That is, if $C,D\in X$, then $C\cup D$ and $C-D\in X$.

But $C,D\in \mathcal X$ means that for indices $k+1\leq a_1<\ldots<a_r\leq n$, $\mu(C\cap A_{a_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{a_r})=\mu(C)\mu(A_{a_1})\ldots\mu(A_{a_r})$, and similarly for $D$. We have to show that $\mu((C\cup D)\cap A_{a_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{a_r})=\mu(C\cup D)\mu(A_{a_1})\ldots\mu(A_{a_r})$. Is this true, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have to show that $\mu((C\cup D)\cap A_{a_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{a_r})=\mu(C\cup D)\mu(A_{a_1})\ldots\mu(A_{a_r})$. Is this true, though?

It's equivalent to show that $\mu((C\cap D)\cap A_{a_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{a_r})=\mu(C\cap D)\mu(A_{a_1})\ldots\mu(A_{a_r})$, but I don't think it's easier to show than the initial result.

We can show that that $\mathcal F_k$ is generated by the partition $\left\{\bigcap_{j=1}^kA_j^{\varepsilon_j},\varepsilon_j\in\{0,1\}\right\}$, where $A^1=A$ and $A^0=\Omega\setminus A$.